# How do I get the selected row ID in a react-bootstrap-table-next?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Is there a way for me to get the Report ID of the row I select? I am using react-bootstrap-table-next and have defined the columns in..
[image]
this manner..

[image]

this is my photos column, I want to get the id and pass it over to my modal component to display the right image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row.reportId to get the id

```
return(
        <div>
          <DefectPhotoModal
             id = {row.reportId}
          />
        </div>
      )
```

Comment: I didn't know that I can get the information like that! However, it keeps running the code instead of only running it when there is an onClick event which results in constantly generating errors. How do I trigger it with only an onClick event?